# How do I perform a saddle point approximation to approximately find the integral $\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \cos^n(x) dx$?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, approximation, approximate-integration

I am supposed to apply the saddle point approximation (i.e. method of steepest descent) to calculate the following integral: $$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \cos^n(x) dx$$ But I have no idea how to write the integral in the form when the saddle point approximation can be used: $$\int_{x_1}^{x_2} e^{f(x)} dx$$

Comment: You can always write $y=e^{\ln(y)}$ if $y$ is not zero. And you can always cut any points where the integrand is zero out of your domain. So...

Comment: $$
\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \cos^n(x) dx=\int_{ - \pi /2}^{\pi /2} {e^{n\log (\cos (x))} dx}  \sim \sqrt {\frac{{2\pi }}{n}} 
$$ (the (simple) saddle point is at $x=0$)